# Filter group id which have at least three "yes" , of which two "yes" must consecutive in column y but in total

Tags: r

I try to filter group id in which (**y ==yes**) value should be consecutive at least two times

```r
DT<-data.frame(id=c(1,1,1, 1,2,2,2,3,3,3, 3,4,4,4), 
               y=c("no", "yes","yes","no","no", "yes", "no","yes","yes","no","yes", "yes","yes","yes"))
DT
```

DT
The result should be:
id y
3 yes
3 yes
3  no
3 yes
4 yes
4 yes
4 yes

I try to use the code:

```r
library(dplyr)
DT %>% group_by(id) %>%
  filter(cumsum(y == 'yes')>1)
```

Comment: When you modify your expected output, as you explained in a comment below, please edit the question accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We could use `rle` to create the condition

```
library(dplyr)
DT %>% 
   group_by(id) %>% 
   filter(any(with(rle(y == 'yes'), lengths[values] > 1))) %>%
   ungroup
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 6 x 3
     id x     y    
  <dbl> <chr> <chr>
1     3 a     yes  
2     3 a     yes  
3     3 b     no   
4     4 a     yes  
5     4 a     yes  
6     4 a     yes
```

---

Or with `rleid` from `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(DT)[DT[, .I[table(rleid(y)[y == 'yes']) > 1],.(id)]$V1]
```

-output

```
 id x   y
1:  3 a yes
2:  3 a yes
3:  3 b  no
4:  4 a yes
5:  4 a yes
6:  4 a yes
```

---

If we want to add a second condition with total number of 'yes'

```
DT %>% 
    group_by(id) %>% 
    filter(any(with(rle(y == 'yes'), lengths[values] > 1))
      , sum(y == 'yes') >2) %>% 
    ungroup
# A tibble: 3 x 3
     id x     y    
  <dbl> <chr> <chr>
1     4 a     yes  
2     4 a     yes  
3     4 a     yes
```

Comment: Thank you very much @akrum.  But I made a little modification on my question as Filter group id which have at least three "yes" , of which two "yes" must consecutive in column y but in total.